# Pygame Stop Light Event

Tags: python, events, python-3.x, event-handling, pygame

I'm trying to create the last example in lab # 8 for the [Program  Arcade Games Book](http://programarcadegames.com/).

The last thing I'm trying to implement is a stoplight that changes colors based on three events and timers.

I understand that I have to use `pygame.time.set_timer()` at one point, but I haven't been exposed to event handling in Pygame yet. I don't know how I should go about making three separate events that would turn each corresponding traffic light its bright color.

This is what I have so far, and if you omit the line `258` to `266`, the animation works using Pygame and Python 3 (I tried concatenating the "events" but its just not working obviously).

Here's a revised version where I tried to use timers to literally just change the color instead of making separate events but its not working in this case either ;(

```
import random
import math

# Requirements:

# Modify the prior Create-a-Picture lab, or start a new one.

# Animate the image. Try one or more of the following:

    # Move an item across the screen.
    # Move an item back and forth.
    # Move up/down/diagonally.
    # Move in circles.
    # Have a person wave his/her arms.
    # Create a stoplight that changes colors.

# import statement
import pygame

# Define colors:
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
DULLRED = (153, 50, 51)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
DULLGREEN = (55, 154, 54)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
LIGHTBLUE = (103, 255, 246)
YELLOW = (252, 255, 31)
DULLYELLOW = (156, 157, 50)

# initialize pygame:
pygame.init()

# screen:
size = (700, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

# Set the caption:
pygame.display.set_caption("Chapter 8 Lab")

# Clock:
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# FPS:
FPS = 60

# boolean variable for game:
done = False

# For loop for white circles:
whiteCircleList = []

for i in range(25):
    x = random.randrange(0, 700)
    y = random.randrange(0, 50)
    whiteCircleList.append([x,y])

# For Loop for Blue Circles:
blueCircleList = []

for i in range(100):
    circleX = random.randrange(0, 500)
    circleY = random.randrange(0, 700)
    blueCircleList.append([circleX, circleY])

# Light Blue Circle For Loop:
lightBlueCircleList = []

for i in range(100):
    circleX = random.randrange(0, 500)
    circleY = random.randrange(0, 700)
    lightBlueCircleList.append([circleX, circleY])

# Surfboard's Rectangle (x-pos, y-pos, x-length, y-length):
surfboardRect = pygame.Rect(325, 225, 50, 150)
boardY = 255.
rectYChange = -5
phase = 0

# Diagonal Rectangle in Top Left Corner:
topLeftDiagonalRect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 10, 10)

# Diagonal Rectangle in Top Right Corner:
topRightDiagonalRect = pygame.Rect(500, 1, 10, 10)

# Diagonal Rectangle Vectors for Top Left Rectangle:
topLeftDiagonalRectXChange = 5
topLeftDiagonalRectYChange = 5

# Diagonal Rectangle Vectors for Top Right Rectangle:
topRightDiagonalRectXChange = -5
topRightDiagonalRectYChange = -5

# Angle for Hand Rotation
handAngle = 0

# Variable for Traffic Light Cover:
currentTopColor = DULLRED

currentMiddleColor = DULLYELLOW

currentBottomColor = GREEN

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    # Game Logic:
    phase += 1

    if phase > 180:
        phase = phase * -1

    # Save exact position as a float to avoid floating point errors:
    boardY += math.cos(math.radians(phase))*2

    surfboardRect.y = int(boardY)

    # Clear the screen:
    screen.fill(RED)

    # Drawing Code:

    # Falling Down circles:
    for i in range(len(whiteCircleList)):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, WHITE, [whiteCircleList[i][0], whiteCircleList[i][1]], 3)
        whiteCircleList[i][1] += 5
        # If the rectangles have hit the bottom of the screen, make them appear 10 pixels above the top:
        if whiteCircleList[i][1] > 450:
            x = random.randrange(0, 700)
            whiteCircleList[i][0] = x
            y = random.randrange(-50, -10)
            whiteCircleList[i][1] = y

    # Red Falling Up Circles:
    for i in range(len(blueCircleList)):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLUE, [blueCircleList[i][0], blueCircleList[i][1]], 5, 5)
        blueCircleList[i][1] -= 5
        if blueCircleList[i][1] < 50:
            circleX = random.randrange(0,700)
            circleY = random.randrange(400, 500)
            blueCircleList[i][0] = circleX
            blueCircleList[i][1] = circleY

    # Light Blue Falling Up Circles:
    for i in range(len(lightBlueCircleList)):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, LIGHTBLUE, [lightBlueCircleList[i][0], lightBlueCircleList[i][1]], 3, 3)
        lightBlueCircleList[i][1] -= 5
        if lightBlueCircleList[i][1] < 50:
            circleX = random.randrange(0, 700)
            circleY = random.randrange(400, 450)
            lightBlueCircleList[i][0] = circleX
            lightBlueCircleList[i][1] = circleY

    # Revised Surfboard Rectangle Code:
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, surfboardRect, 0)

    # Top Left Diagonal Rectangle Code:
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, topLeftDiagonalRect, 0)

    # Add The Top Left Diagonal Rectangle Change Vectors
    topLeftDiagonalRect.x += topLeftDiagonalRectXChange
    topLeftDiagonalRect.y += topLeftDiagonalRectYChange

    # Top and Bottom Screen Collision:
    if topLeftDiagonalRect.y >= 500 or topLeftDiagonalRect.y <= 0:
        topLeftDiagonalRectYChange = topLeftDiagonalRectYChange * -1

    # Left and Right Screen Collision:
    if topLeftDiagonalRect.x <= 0 or topLeftDiagonalRect.x >= 700:
        topLeftDiagonalRectXChange = topLeftDiagonalRectXChange * -1

    # Draw the top right rectangle:
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, topRightDiagonalRect, 0)

    # Add the change vectors for the Top Right Rectangle:
    topRightDiagonalRect.x += topRightDiagonalRectXChange
    topRightDiagonalRect.y += topRightDiagonalRectYChange

    # Top and Bottom Screen Collision:
    if topRightDiagonalRect.y <= 0 or topRightDiagonalRect.y >= 500:
        topRightDiagonalRectYChange = topRightDiagonalRectYChange * -1

    # Left and Right Screen Collision:
    if topRightDiagonalRect.x <= 0 or topRightDiagonalRect.x >= 700:
        topRightDiagonalRectXChange = topRightDiagonalRectXChange * -1

    # Person Waving His Arms:
    # Head:
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, WHITE, [575, 300], 15)

    # Body:
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLUE, [560, 315, 30, 60], 0)

    # Left Rotating Hand:
    # Left Hand's Original Dimensions:
    # pygame.draw.line(screen, WHITE, [560, 315], [540, 295], 5)

    # Original Hand's x position based on the rotating circle idea:
    # handX = 40 * math.sin(handAngle) + 560

    # Original Hand's y position based on the rotating circle idea:
    # handY = 40 * math.cos(handAngle) + 315
    handPosition = (40 * math.sin(handAngle) + 560, 40 * math.cos(handAngle) + 315)

    pygame.draw.line(screen, WHITE, [560, 315], handPosition, 4)

    # Increase the hand angle by 0.05 Radians:
    handAngle = handAngle + 0.05

    # Reset the angle after a full sweep:
    pi = 3.141592653

    if handAngle > 2 * pi:
        handAngle = handAngle - 2*pi

    # Right Immobile Hand:
    pygame.draw.line(screen, WHITE, [590, 315], [590, 340], 4)

    # Left Leg:
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, [560, 375, 10, 20], 0)

    # Right Leg:
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, [580, 375, 10, 20], 0)

    # Left Shoe Ellipse
    # Ellipse Notes: ellipse(Surface, color, Rect, width=0) -> Rect
    pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, BLACK, [550, 390, 20, 15], 0)

    # Right Shoe Ellipse:
    pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, BLACK, [580, 390, 20, 15], 0)

    # Add in a changing traffic light
    # Rectangle for Traffic Light:
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, [50, 350, 50, 100], 0)

    # Traffic Light Post:
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLACK, [65, 450, 20, 40], 0)

    # Top light:
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, currentTopColor, [75, 370], 12)

    # Second light:
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, currentMiddleColor, [75, 400], 12)

    # Third light:
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, currentBottomColor, [75, 430], 12)

    # Three events must be cycled to change each of the traffic light colors
    # from their dull versions to their fullest color forms

    # The question is, can this be achieved through a timer?

    # 60 frames per second is on the timer itself so every 180 frames would mean
    # 3 seconds, or every 300 frames would mean 5 seconds

    # DOCS on set timer: set_timer(eventid, milliseconds)

##    turnRedLightOn = pygame.draw.circle(screen, RED, [75, 370], 12)
##                   + pygame.draw.circle(screen, DULLYELLOW, [75, 400], 12)
##                   + pygame.draw.circle(screen, DULLGREEN, [75, 430], 12)

    # Turn the top light red and all other lights dull every three seconds
    pygame.time.set_timer(currentTopColor = RED, 3000)
    pygame.time.set_timer(currentMiddleColor = DULLYELLOW, 3000)
    pygame.time.set_timer(currentBottomColor = DULLGREEN, 3000)

    # Turn the middle light yellow and all other lights dull every six seconds
    pygame.time.set_timer(currentTopColor = DULLRED, 6000)
    pygame.time.set_timer(currentMiddleColor = YELLOW, 6000)
    pygame.time.set_timer(currentBottomColor = DULLGREEN, 6000)

    # Turn the bottom light green and all other lights dull every nine seconds
    pygame.time.set_timer(currentTopColor = DULLRED, 9000)
    pygame.time.set_timer(currentMiddleColor = DULLYELLOW, 9000)
    pygame.time.set_timer(currentBottomColor = GREEN, 9000)


    # Update the screen:
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Clock FPS:
    clock.tick(FPS)

# Quit after main game loop ends:
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Many times it's easier for us to find the problem if you boil the code down to be [*Minimal*, Complete, Tested and Readable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You posted this exact question yesterday... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861316/need-help-creating-a-stop-light-event-in-pygame-python-3?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

The `set_timer` shouldn't execute in every cycle of the main loop, you can call it outside and it will repeat itself every 3000ms.

```
# Current Light
light_on = 0  # 0-red 1-yellow 2-green

LIGHTS_EVENT = pygame.USERVENT + 0   # Event code for Lights change
pygame.time.set_timer(LIGHTS_EVENT, 3000)

while not done:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        if event.type == LIGHTS_EVENT:
            light_on += 1
            if light_on == 3:
                light_on = 0


    currentTopColor = DULLRED
    currentMiddleColor = DULLYELLOW
    currentBottomColor = DULLGREEN
    if light_on == 0:
        currentTopColor = RED
    if light_on == 1:
        currentMiddleColor = YELLOW
    if light_on == 2:
        currentBottomColor = GREEN

    # Top light:
    ...
```